# no other flower in the park vs no other flowers in the park

Tags: sentence-construction

(a) No other flower in the park is as expensive as orchids.

(b) No other flowers in the park are as expensive as orchids .

Which one is correct ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a connection between flower in the first clause and orchid in the second clause. As such, the numbers must match. Valid sentences are therefore

> No other flower in the park is as expensive as an orchid.
>
> No other flowers in the park are as expensive as orchids.

Your sentence **a** is not appropriate because flower is singular and orchids is plural.

Comment: Would you say then that "No flower in the park is as expensive as orchids are" is grammatically incorrect, JavaLatte?

Comment: @John Clifford: good point. The problem is the shared verb: if you put a separate verb for the second clause, flower and orchid don't have to be the same number.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

> (a) No other flower in the park is as expensive as orchids.
>
> (b) No other flowers in the park are as expensive as orchids .

The word **other** in your example suggests orchids are also found in the park, but American and British speakers of English tend not to find orchids in our parks. So let's change the sentence:

> No other tree on the street is as foul-smelling as the ginkgo.
>
> No other trees on the street are as foul-smelling as the ginkgo.

The singular is certainly correct, and the plural is marginally correct. You'll hear both forms in conversation, especially in contexts where the noun refers to something which lacks personality and individuality  (trees, flowers, cars, etc). However, the plural is less likely when the noun refers to a something that does not typically exist as an undifferentiated multitude but as something or someone possessing unique characteristics:

> No other president was as popular as President X.
>
> No other presidents were as popular as President X.  <sup>less
>   likely/marginal</sup>
>
> No other striker has scored as many goals in a single season.
>
> No other strikers have scored as many goals in a single season. <sup>less
>   likely/marginal</sup>